# How to change Ubuntu installer

Tags: 20.04, system-installation

So I want to make a Linux distro using this tool called cubic but you are limited to just a chroot terminal and I know how to change the splash screen so it doesn’t show the Ubuntu logo but do not know how to change the installer like change the images text and the text of a option so like when it is installing Ubuntu the pictures will be my pictures and instead of one of the option saying try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu change it to try example name install example name.Does anyone know how to do this?Thank you.

Comment: Mkusb makes persistent USB's that use GRUB for booting like Full installs do. Perhaps make a USB using mkusb and experiment with modifying grub.cfg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubiquity is the name of the Ubuntu installer application.
The corresponding package is simply named `ubiquity`.
The `ubiquity` package is available in the Live Environment, but it is removed once the system has been installed. (On Cubic's Packages page, you should see Ubiquity flagged for removal).
Therefore, if you want to modify aspects of the installer, you can modify files related to Ubiquity.

However, based on your question, I think you will be more interested in another package: `ubiquity-slideshow`. This package is also available in the Live Environment.

Files for this package are located in the `/usr/share/ubiquity-slideshow/` directory.

- There are lots of HTML files here that can easily be modified if you want to display something different during the installation process.
- `/usr/share/ubiquity-slideshow/slideshow.conf` sets the window size for the installer.
- The actual screenshots you see are stored in `/usr/share/ubiquity-slideshow/slides/screenshots`.

In Cubic, you can use nano to edit any of the HTML files. However, you can always list the contents of a file (using `cat <file name>`, then select-and-copy the text to edit it outside of Cubic. When you are done editing, save the file on your host machine, and then drag it onto the Cubic Terminal window to overwrite the old file.

Likewise, to change the images in the  `/usr/share/ubiquity-slideshow/slides/screenshots`, simply drag your new image files on to the Terminal page to copy them. (Use the same names as the original image files, to avoid having to change code).

Before copying, remember to `cd` to the directory first, because Cubic will copy files to your *current* location. So, to change the screenshots, use `cd /usr/share/ubiquity-slideshow/slides/screenshots` before dragging the new files onto the window.

If you want to work with the `ubiquity-slideshow` files on your host machine, you can download the entire deb package for from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu/download) for Ubuntu 20.04. Use Archive Manager to extract the deb file (don't install it!) to a temporary directory so you can make changes to the HTML or image files. Then copy only the changed files into Cubic.

Comment: Yeah this was very helpful I thought I would have to do something similar to this because that’s what I had to do with the splash screen

Comment: Ok I think I did that